# Do the Android emulators actually exist as devices?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to know if the emulators available in java ADT are present in the real world? What I am asking is that if I test my app on all the available emulators in java ADT will that be sufficient to know how my app will look like on all the devices? Plus the arabic words appear as separated letters on devices with old versions so will they appear that way on real devices or just on the emulators?

Comment: This is a very broad question. There are innumerous variants of models e.g. Galaxy S4 GT i9505, i9500, i9505GE, i9506 and so on. There are also many, many Chinese Android devices not from major manufacturers. The emulator list is not exhaustive. There is a great spread of different devices there though but I sincerely doubt it EVER will have EVERY android device on it. I don't know about Arabic chars I'm afraid. What version of the SDK are you using? What version are you testing on?

Comment: SDK is revision 21.1 and I am testing on android 2.2; how can I view what will it look like on real android 2.2 device cz mine is later version... and I need to know if I tested my app on the  available emulators in android sdk will that be sufficient to know how will my app look like on the devices?

Comment: There isn't a totally clear answer I can give (though others may) It will align the resolution etc, but you can't ever entirely predict what HTC Sense, Samsung Touchwiz, Motoblur etc etc will ACTUALLY display on the device. The emulator is a guide only. Keep in mind that if you deploy the app users will give you feedback by email or on the Play store directly so you can tweek / bugfix for various devices. Your main initial concerns are screen size and resolution to ensure layout and legibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on its your real screen resolution...it will be aligned as in emulator..if you are testing on emulator by changing different resolutions and devices,it will look like what you are seen in emulator on the devices.but the problem is it has chance that the size of the views may change on the devices..for example if you are looking for a button which is at a distance of 10dp from both sides,it should not be make any effect on your emulator,but when it is on devices it looks very small and will be difficult to use..

Comment: ok and if I tested it on the emulators how can I make sure that it's displayed correctly on all the available devices (real devices)?

Comment: try this like when you launch your emulator,tick on scale display to real size and give the screen size(inches)..but it is not as much accurate..it is ok to some extend.If you need an accurate result you have to check in devices..